# Unable to install mysql 5.7.32 on Ubuntu, using old mysql archive version 5.7.32

Tags: mysql

I have following files ready with me:

```
libmysqlclient20_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb 
mysql-common_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb       
mysql-community-test_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
libmysqlclient-dev_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb 
mysql-community-client_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb 
mysql-server_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
libmysqld-dev_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb    
mysql-community-server_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb 
mysql-testsuite_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
mysql-client_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb   
mysql-community-source_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

I tried following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-common_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

It is displaying following output:

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading mysql-common from 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 to 5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04
(Reading database ... 183026 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-common_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04) over (5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-common_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/docs/INFO_BIN', which is also in package mysql-server-8.0 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common_5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Do you have MySQL 8.0 on the machine as well? If not, was MySQL 8.0 previously installed on this computer? Which version of Ubuntu are you running? I'm seeing you're trying to install a package suited for 18.04, but the error message points to having 20.04 packages installed.

Comment: *Why* do you want 5.7 over 5.8?

Comment: I need 5.7 because I have mysql dump backup which I want to execute and on newer version it is  giving error saying check mysql version

Comment: Yes I have MySQL 0.0 in my machine , Ubuntu Version I am using 20.04